# How to call get_balance function in eos contract in 1.3.2?

Tags: smart-contract

In the old version, I can get self balance by these code:

`auto token = eosio::token(N(eosio.token));
        const asset balance =
            token.get_balance(_self, symbol_type(EOS_SYMBOL).name());`

But when I upgrade repo to 1.3.2 eosio-cpp, and using [eosio.token.hpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/tree/master/eosio.token), I don't even know how to initial the class, because the constructor has been removed.

So how to write the code above in higher version?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it ;-)

action

```
// START balance get
ACTION balance(name user) {
    const symbol sym(symbol_code("EOS"), 4);
    const auto my_balance = eosio::token::get_balance("eosio.token"_n, get_self(), sym.code());
    print("my balance is ", my_balance);
}
// END balance get
```

eosio.token.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <eosiolib/asset.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

#include <string>

namespace eosiosystem {
class system_contract;
}

namespace eosio {

using std::string;

CONTRACT token: public contract {
public:
    using contract::contract;

    ACTION create(name issuer, asset maximum_supply);

    ACTION issue(name to, asset quantity, string memo);

    ACTION retire(asset quantity, string memo);

    ACTION transfer(name from, name to, asset quantity, string memo);

    ACTION open(name owner, const symbol& symbol, name ram_payer);

    ACTION close(name owner, const symbol& symbol);

    static asset get_supply(name token_contract_account, symbol_code sym_code) {
        stats statstable(token_contract_account, sym_code.raw());
        const auto& st = statstable.get(sym_code.raw());
        return st.supply;
    }

    static asset get_balance(name token_contract_account, name owner, symbol_code sym_code) {
        accounts accountstable(token_contract_account, owner.value);
        const auto& ac = accountstable.get(sym_code.raw());
        return ac.balance;
    }

private:
    TABLE account {
        asset balance;

        uint64_t primary_key() const {
            return balance.symbol.code().raw();
        }
    };

    TABLE currency_stats {
        asset supply;
        asset max_supply;
        name issuer;

        uint64_t primary_key() const {
            return supply.symbol.code().raw();
        }
    };

    typedef eosio::multi_index<"accounts"_n, account> accounts;
    typedef eosio::multi_index<"stat"_n, currency_stats> stats;

    void sub_balance(name owner, asset value);
    void add_balance(name owner, asset value, name ram_payer);
};

} /// namespace eosio
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, i got it, just like this

`asset pool_eos = eosio::token::get_balance("eosio.token"_n,get_self(), symbol_code("EOS"));`

Comment: it seems not right.........